# Fix Special Symbols that are rendering like this: â€™s

Tags: jquery, special-characters, character

I need to convert any special symbols coming through in my json file to render correctly.  Right now they are showing up like this

Testâ€™s

Instead of like this

Test's

I am grabbing all the data from a json file like this:

```
$.each(results.Blogs, function(i, blog){    
    blogCount.push(i);
    topicsBlog.push({
        indexRank: i,
            blogDescription: blog.Description,
            blogDate: blog.PubDate,
            blogTitle: blog.Title,
            blogLink: blog.Link
        });
});
```

and putting it in my html using Jquery templates:

```
$('#topic-blog-links').html($('#topic-blog').tmpl(blogSplice));
```

Is there a solution to fix these characters?

Comment: Not 100%, but maybe something with UTF-8?

Comment: Please post the code you are using to display this data. It looks like unicode for a symbol that's similar to an apostrophe but isn't. I suspect you are using a method that's not unicode aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your character encoding must be UTF-8 end-to-end. You need to declare this in your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

And the data that you've stored on the server must be saved in UTF-8 format. If it was some dump from MS-Word (Windows-1251 format), you're out of luck.

Comment: I think this is the fix i needed

Comment: Great. Please select this answer.

Comment: end-to-end of course, but meta tag's only one part of it. Check your database encoding, response header, and any socket/stream you're using.